# What will be Redirect URL of Azure Active Directory while setting up for nativescript mobile app

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, nativescript, office365api, nativescript-plugin

I want to login with office 365 in my mobile app(nativescript+angular). How to configure Azure Active Directory. What will be Redirect URL?

Comment: Are you using nativescript-oauth2?

Comment: If any answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I m using nativescript-oauth2

Answer (score 0):

Please referred to this document: [Add redirect URI(s) to your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#add-redirect-uris-to-your-application).

For public applications, provide the URI used by Azure AD to return token responses. Enter a value specific to your application, for example: `https://MyFirstApp`.

Make sure that it matches with the URL customized in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's the native script. If you're using ADAL, please follow below:

It's determined by your application on different platforms.

### On iOS, it's with the Bundle Id of your app:

App Redirect URI: `x-msauth-mytestiosapp://com.myapp.mytestapp`

See more details here:https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc/wiki/sso

### On Android, it's with the certificate fingerprint of your app in the Google play store:

`msauth://packagename/Base64UrlEncodedSignature(Cert fingerprint`

For example,
`msauth://com.example.userapp/IcB5PxIyvbLkbFVtBI%2FitkW%2Fejk%3D`

See more details here: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android/wiki/sso

---

If you're using ADAL.js, you can just use your applications's URL.